# How to authenticate without password on Chef deployed nodes

Tags: ssh, chef, ssh-keys

I started to use Chef to deal with DevOps automation and now I have a situation were there are two database servers(primary and secondary) being deployed using `knife server create` , and during the chef-client bootstrap processes, there is a recipe that deals with a script that activates database replication between these two nodes.

The problem is, this database replication involves a `ssh` at some point, but because these nodes are new, they don't know about each other (there is only the chef server machine in `.ssh/authorized_keys`), so if I run the script, it will get stuck asking for the ssh password...

I'm new to ssh keys, so what could be the best approach to handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get SSH configured (including swapping SSH host keys) before you SSH.

Comment: @womble That makes sense, but its possible without inputing password? When `knife server create` creates the machine, it automatically adds the chef-server machine key as a 'authorized_key'

Comment: I don't know about the chefisms, because I don't use it, but it's certainly possible to do because I do it with Puppet all the time.